# Is there a way to use js Notification with set_flashdata codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

> Using Codeigniter 3

I'm a beginner.

I have tried more and more to use 
[Notification Styles Inspiration](http://tympanus.net/Development/NotificationStyles/) with `$this->session->set_flashdata('', '')` but I fail. I don't know how to call show notification method in js when I place flash data `$this->session->flashdata('messagename')`

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple toaster, instead of using external one.

Html code

```
<div class="toast toast-default">
    <button class="toast-dismiss"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        Oops!!! Something went wrong while adding this product. Please try again after sometime.
</div>
```

Css

```
.toast-default {
    background: rgba(53, 164, 178, 0.8) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.toast {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none; <--- if flashdata is set make it block.
    padding: 20px 10px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

BY default, tost is display none.

If flashdata is set, make it display block.